# I want to show restaurant name and their respective food item name one below the other

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables "restaurants" having columns (id, Rname, email) and "food_items" having columns (id, item_name, item_price, Rname). Now i want develop a page in which all the restaurants and their respective food items will show. like below:

```
Restaurant Name1:
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

I tried a lot for this but i'm not getting the exact thing what i want.
I wrote a sql query which show the restaurant name then their item name but it's not giving me exact thing.

```
<?php

$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT mi.item_name, mi.item_price, mi.veg_nonveg, rs.Rname FROM menu_items AS mi LEFT JOIN restaurants AS rs ON mi.Rname=rs.Rname";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)){
    foreach ($result1 as $rows) {
    echo "<br>" . $rows['item_name'] . " " . $rows['item_price'] . " " . 
    $rows['Rname'];
    }
    }
```

Actual result is:

```
item_name, item_price , Restaurant name (Rname)

chicken curry 105 abc
veg fried rice 101 abc
Veg Momos 50 abc
veg fried rice 100 xyz
```

Expected Result :

```
ABC:
Chicken curry 105
veg fried rice 101
veg momos 50

xyz:
veg fried rice 100
```

Comment: What if a restaurant serves more than 3 items?

Comment: I don't see any effort to group them by restaurant

Comment: Restaurant can serve as many items as it want , actually there is one page aslo in which restaurant can add food items .

Comment: I'm not much experienced in PHP so i need your help , i just did these things.

Comment: You can either `GROUP_CONCAT` the items in your query, grouping by restaurant, or build a php structure regrouping the items of each restaurant, from the query result. I would suggest the latter

Comment: Select all items joined with restaurant ordered by restaurant name.  Loop through the results.  If the current restaurant name does not match the previous name, output the restaurant name, then the food item.  If the restaurant name does match, then only output the food item name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing that from `sql`, you can achieve the same from `php`:

For example if your data received from database is this:

```
$data = [
    ['Rname' => 'Restaurant 1', 'item_name' => 'foo', 'item_price' => '354631', 'veg_nonveg' => 'veg'],
    ['Rname' => 'Restaurant 1', 'item_name' => 'bar', 'item_price' => '234631', 'veg_nonveg' => 'veg'],
    ['Rname' => 'Restaurant 2', 'item_name' => 'foo', 'item_price' => '334234', 'veg_nonveg' => 'non-veg'],
    ['Rname' => 'Restaurant 2', 'item_name' => 'bar', 'item_price' => '45353', 'veg_nonveg' => 'non-veg'],
];
```

You can do something like this:

```
// To print restaurant name only once in a group we need to store the 
// already printed restaurant somewhere.

$restaurant = ''; // declared this variable to store current restaurant.

foreach ($data as $row) {

    // checking if current restaurant is already printed. 
    if ($restaurant != $row['Rname']) {
        //if current restaurant is not printed then we will print new one and store new restaurant.
        $restaurant = $row['Rname'];
        echo $row['Rname'] . "\r\n";
    }

    // here we are doing the regular stuff.
    echo $row['item_name']. ' ' .$row['item_price']. ' ' . $row['veg_nonveg']. "\r\n";
}
```

check the working example here: [working example](https://ideone.com/W0br0C)

**Edit**:

**Another way:**

For instance we have two tables:

Author:

```
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | description |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | abc  | som         |
|  2 | def  | description |
|  3 | ghi  | here        |
+----+------+-------------+
```

Book:

```
+----+------+------+-----------+
| id | name | year | author_id |
+----+------+------+-----------+
|  1 | ijk  | 1990 |         1 |
|  2 | lmn  | 1991 |         1 |
|  3 | opq  | 1995 |         2 |
|  4 | rst  | 1996 |         2 |
|  5 | uvw  | 2000 |         3 |
|  6 | xyz  | 2001 |         3 |
+----+------+------+-----------+
```

The easiest way to fetch data is to run two `sql` queries:

First fetch authors:

```sql
SELECT * FROM author;
```

Then fetch their books by author's IDs:

```sql
SELECT * FROM book where author_id IN (1,2,3);
```

Now to print author's books in group we can print books by `author_id`:

```
foreach ($authors as $author) {
    echo $author['name'] . "\r\n";

    foreach ($books as $book) {
        if ($book['id'] == $author['author_id']) {
            echo $book['name']. ' ' .$book['year']. "\r\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Although we are running two queries here but this is much cleaner way of managing data. It also makes things easier when implementing pagination.

Comment: Hi Aakash , Thank you very much for your help. It's working as expected. I have one small request can you please explain me this code?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change in your query like below . try this one Hope it helps

```
$sql1 = "SELECT concat(GROUP_CONCAT(mi.item_name, mi.item_price),'"<br>"') as name_price, mi.veg_nonveg, rs.Rname FROM menu_items AS mi JOIN restaurants AS rs ON mi.Rname=rs.Rname group by rs.Rname";

 $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result1)){
     foreach ($result1 as $rows) {
       echo $rows['Rname']."<br>" . $rows['name_price'];
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hi gaurav, thanks for your help. I tried your code but is solve only one prblm (it's not repeating Restaurant name but it's repeating item name and price. like this:

abc
Veg Momos50,chicken curry105,veg fried rice101,veg fried rice101,Veg Momos50,chicken curry105
name
veg fried rice100